# how to merge same sheet across multiple excel which contain multiple sheets each into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\Users\zachip_\OneDrive\Documents'

files = glob.glob(path + '\*.xlsx*')
dfs=[]
sheet_names=['Sheet1','Sheet2']
dft=[]

for file in files:
    file = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    i=0
    while i<=enumerate(file.sheet_names):
        for sheet in file.sheet_names:
            if sheet ==sheet_names[i]:
               df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=sheet)
               dfs.append(df)
               i+=1
        x= pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
        dft.append(x)
```

background: within the path there are few excel files which each of them contain multiple sheets, I need to merge the sheet 1 from excel 1 with sheet 1 from excel 2 into a dataframe 1, and sheet 2 from excel 1 and sheet 2 from excel 2 into dataframe2, could anyone please advice how should i correct my code? i am seriously stuck and needed help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code might do the trick:

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = '/Users/erikingwersen/Downloads/example'
files = glob.glob(path + '/*.xlsx*')
# `files` for me, will contain the following filepaths:
#
# ['/Users/erikingwersen/Downloads/example/test2.xlsx',
#  '/Users/erikingwersen/Downloads/example/test1.xlsx',
#  '/Users/erikingwersen/Downloads/example/Optimization Variables Summary.xlsx']
#
# From these filepaths, only `test1.xlsx` and `test2.xlsx` Excel files contain
# both `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` sheets.

# Define the names of the sheets that the Excel files must have.
sheet_names = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2']

# Create a dictionary of lists, where each key is a sheet name, and each value
# is an empty list. In the next step, we'll append the DataFrames from the Excel
# files that contain both `Sheet1`, and `Sheet2` sheets to their respective
# lists.
dfs = {sheet: [] for sheet in sheet_names}

# Iterate the Excel files that were found inside the `path` directory.
for file in files:
    # Read the Excel file. By setting `sheet_name=None`, we're essentially
    # telling Pandas to read all sheets in the Excel file.
    df_dict = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None)
    # Check if the Excel file that we read has all the required sheets.
    # NOTE: the Excel file might have extra sheets, other than
    #       `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`. These extra sheets if any, will be ignored.
    if any(sheet not in df_dict for sheet in sheet_names):
        continue
    # Append the DataFrames from each sheet to their respective lists.
    for sheet in sheet_names:
        df = df_dict[sheet]
        dfs[sheet].append(df)

# Create the final DataFrame by concatenating each list of DataFrames
df_sheet1 = pd.concat(dfs['Sheet1'])
df_sheet2 = pd.concat(dfs['Sheet2'])
```

Comment: yes it works well for me, thanks so much for helping it means a lot!!! will accept your answer once i have enough reputation credit to do it! thanks for the kindness